# extension error import js in a ts file typescript jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

I'm importing app.js inside a .test.ts file when i run npm test i received the error

my import

```
import { buildApp } from '../../../src/app.js';
```

ERROR

```
Cannot 
find module '../../../src/app.js' from '__tests__/integration-tests/resolvers/customer.test.ts'
```

I changed all my files removing the extensions and test and dev execution works, but start(/dist) stop working... what i'm doing wrong...

my scripts

```
"scripts": {    
    "build:ts": "tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/index.ts",
    "start": "node ./dist/src/index.js",
    "test": "node --no-warnings --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand"
  }
```

i would like to run dev, test and start without any problems...
I don't know why jest can't read .js file...

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between node requiring the .js extensions in the import and jest not able to revolve import with the extensions.

I solved this issue for myself by adding the following configuration inside my jest.config.ts:

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
  "(.+)\\.js": "$1",
},
```

Source of inspiration: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1057#issuecomment-1068342692

Hope this help